# Python: ¿cómo acelerar la ejecución de un programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He realizado el siguiente programa (con ayuda de vosotros) que imprime en un fichero todas las rutas de los archivos y carpetas que contiene una ruta dada:

```
from os import walk, getcwd

def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
    for root, subdirs, archivos in walk(ruta):
        f = open("ficheroderutas.txt","a",encoding="utf8")
        for archivo in archivos:
             f.write(root+'\\'+archivo+"\n")
        for subdir in subdirs:
            f.write(root+'\\'+subdir+"\n")
        f.close()
    return
```

El problema que tengo es que al poner: `ls(ruta='C:\\')`ya que quiero guardar en un archivo todas las rutas a archivos y carpetas de mi disco duro, me tarda varios minutos en hacer dicha tarea (generandome un archivo txt de casi 30MB).
Me preguntaba si hay una manera más rápida de ejecutar este código o cualquier otro. No busco cambiar el código, a menos que sea para aprovechar características de alguna librería que permita paralelización, algo parecido al fork de c...supongo que existirá. Porque este último punto es importante ya que tengo varios núcleos en mi ordenador. Bueno, la respuesta podría ser muy extensa o no tanto. Básicamente las opciones que me suenan son:

- generar un .exe de mi programa, ya que supongo que si se escribiera en código máquina ya compilado para dárselo al micro correría más rápido que ejecutándolo por el interprete.
- Traducirlo a c, preferiblemente con un traductor python->c (se llama así, verdad?), aunque supongo que el problema la automatización este tipo de tareas de rescritura de programas no dan lugar a un código tan eficiente como si lo reescribiera uno mismo.
- Usar alguna librería de python que me permita paralelizar mi código.

¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna otra opción?. No sé si existe alguna otra opción. De existir la librería de paralelización ¿Cómo se llama?

SO: WXP SP3

Python 3.4.4

Comment: He generado un .exe con cx_freeze, y no parece haber una diferencia de velocidad significativa.

Comment: Paralelización, no; Concurrencia, tal vez. Nunca permitir que una librería lance múltiples hilos de ejecución fuera del control del hilo de ejecución principal (y no quiero decir que no sea práctica habitual). En tu caso, `os.walk` es muy, muy lento. En cada iteración tiene que volver a chequear la lista `subdirs` y determinar qué subdirectorios listar. Cuantos más subdirectorios, más lento. Te recomiendo hacerte tu propio algoritmo con `os.scandir()`. En cuanto a aplicar concurrencia, aprovecha los `Futures` del módulo `concurrent.futures`. No tengo tiempo ahora para ponerte un ejemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El mayor problema de tu código es que estas constantemente abriendo y cerrando un archivo, simplificando esto ya reduces el tiempo mucho (en mi caso se reduce de 164 segundos a 7 segundos):

```
from os import walk, getcwd

def ls(ruta = getcwd()):
    with open("ficheroderutas.txt", "a", encoding="utf8") as f :
        for root, subdirs, archivos in walk(ruta):
            for archivo in archivos:
                f.write(root + '\\'+archivo+"\n")
            for subdir in subdirs:
                f.write(root + '\\'+subdir+"\n")
```

De esta forma solo abres una vez el archivo. Ten en cuenta que usando `with` el archivo se cierra automáticamente al terminar la función. El `return` es también innecesario.

Comment: Gracias por tu código, aunque en mi ordenador no parece ser tan rápido, no al menos en una diferencia de 2 órdenes de magnitud. En velocidad es similar al mío, ambos me tardan varios minutos. De todas formas, la tuya no es una respuesta a mi pregunta porque mi pregunta no va sobre reescribir el código en si mismo sino sobre usar otros recursos como los que menciono que me suenan.

Comment: @Mr. Baldan, ten en cuenta que no todos los sistemas operativos funcionan igual con python. Si lo que buscas es mejorar rendimientos, te recomiendo que añadas a tu pregunta el sistema operativo que usas y los número de versiones python y windows.

Comment: @Mr.Baldan  Cuando dices "mi pregunta no va sobre reescribir el código en si mismo ", ten en cuenta que un código que abre y cierra un archivo tantas veces es simplemente un código tan ineficiente que se podría considerar erróneo. Así, yo como mínimo cambiaría eso

Answer (score 1):

**Si quieres optimizar algo, tienes que saber qué es lo que está ralentizando**. Pensar en paralelizar o en pasar rutinas a C++ es matar moscas a cañonazos. Vamos, que no te recomiendo perder el tiempo en eso, si no sabes a priori que te va a solucionar algo.

Al menos, vigila el nivel de carga de la CPU mientras se ejecuta el programa. A lo mejor lo que más te tarda es el disco duro en leer todo el disco, y ahí poco vas a poder mejorar el código, ya que no es cuestión de que el procesador no de más de si. Por cierto, ¿tu disco duro es SSD?

También hay que aplicar un poco de "pensamiento lateral" Por ejemplo: ¿cuál es el fin del programa? ¿monitorizar cambios en el sistema de archivo? En ese caso, utilizar un monitor de eventos..

Ya que parece que te interesa el tema, ¿porqué no aprendes sobre *profiling*? Puedes empezar con cProfile, que es muy sencillito.